# Why I cannot comment VBA code with an apostrophe?

Tags: vba, comments

All

I am learning VBA with MS Excel 2007, and am trying to comment a code chunk out from my code.

I think the apostrophe can help me to achieve this. However, the code after the apostrophe is just keeping the same colour (black), while the correct colour of a comment line should be green. I even copy an apostrophe from a code example and paste it into my code, but still got nothing.

May I know how can I add a comment from my VBA code?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show an example of your code and where you’re trying to place the comment, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All

Thanks for your advice. It turns out that I have to move the cursor away from the comment line and then it will appear to be green and commented.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2007 : The apostrophe is correct for commenting.  Perhaps the font color is set to black ? Enter VBA, and then go to Tools/Options/Editor Format. Then select "comment text". Set the foreground color to the green you like!

Comment: Hi, Steven. Thanks for the advice. I did what you recommended, and found that the front colour of comment text is green. So I guess it is not the case.